# MariaDB - Can't get my check constraint to work effectively

Tags: mysql, mariadb

So I have this code:

Essentially, I want to be able to insert any type of rating without the requirement of a comment. However, a comment cannot be left unless a rating has been left. For example, `insert into movie_rating(movie_quality_rating) values(1);` will yield this error: `ERROR 4025 (23000): CONSTRAINT movie_rating.theatre_food_comment failed for test_db.movie_rating`.

This is the logical I want to accomplish (the rating has to relate to it's relevant comment. ex. movie comment with movie rating:

```
rating without comment = yes
comment without ratting = no
comment with rating = yes
```

Sorry if I am wasting anyone's times but I've been stuck on this for days and I'm pretty much a noob and have tried searching everywhere but this is my last resort. I appreciate any ounce of help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use table-level check constraints to test multiple columns.

```
CREATE TABLE movie_rating (
  customer int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  
  movie_quality_rating int(1) CHECK (movie_quality_rating between 1 and 10),
  movie_quality_comment varchar(255),
  
  theatre_food_rating int(1) CHECK (theatre_food_rating between 1 and 10),
  theatre_food_comment varchar(255),
  
  overall_rating int(1) CHECK (overall_rating between 1 and 10),
  overall_comment varchar(255),

  CHECK (movie_quality_comment IS NULL OR movie_quality_rating IS NOT NULL),
  CHECK (theatre_food_comment IS NULL OR theatre_food_rating IS NOT NULL),
  CHECK (overall_comment IS NULL OR overall_rating IS NOT NULL),
  PRIMARY KEY (customer)
);
```

Comment: Single `CHECK (rating IS NOT NULL OR comment IS NULL)` is enough.

Comment: Thanks. I knew there was a simplification, but was having trouble figuring it out.

Comment: when I paste your answer into the MariaDB console I get this error: ```ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '),
  CHECK (overall_comment IS NULL OR overall_rating IS NOT NULL),
  PRIMARY...' at line 14```

Comment: Sorry, I missed something when editing.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for helping out by the way. So, the logic of the code does not work as expected. I ran this ```insert into movie_rating(movie_quality_comment) values ('hey');``` and the query inserted the value 'hey' into the table but it was not supposed to as a "movie_rating" had not been left. If a movie_rating has not been left, then a movie comment cannot be inserted. Does that make sense? Sorry, I'm really bad at explaining. EDIT: So I've just been testing it, and it seems like this only happens with movie_comment and movie_rating but the others work as expected. Hmmmm.

Comment: I had another editing error. Try now.

Comment: thank you so much man. Literally worked a charm. Such a legend. Have a great day my man. :))))))